# Crop Images in CSS without setting dimensions

Tags: css, sass

I know `object-fit: cover;` is a great way to crop images in css, but is it possible to use this in the same way, without specifying the dimensions? Instead just having it fill to the width of the parent element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `object-fit: cover;` too. Just make sure to specify `width: 100%` and `height: 100%` for the image. For this solution to work, the parent element will need to have a defined height, otherwise the image will be displayed as it is.

```html
<p>Parent element with no dimensions (default width to 100%): will maintain image aspect ratio (all image is visible).</p>
<div>
  <img src="https://img.elo7.com.br/product/original/1B9A0FE/painel-1x0-70-bob-esponja-painel.jpg" style="object-fit: cover; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
</div>
<p>Parent element with specified dimensions: image will cover the area.</p>
<div style="width: 300px; height: 100px;">
  <img src="https://img.elo7.com.br/product/original/1B9A0FE/painel-1x0-70-bob-esponja-painel.jpg" style="object-fit: cover; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`background-size: cover;` should do the trick.

Comment: Only if it's for decoration purposes. If the image isn't decorative, it should not be displayed as a background.

Comment: Is it possible to use this without setting the image as a background image?

Comment: I don't think so.